# java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA1 signature file digest for org/bouncycastle/tsp/TimeStampTokenInfo.class

Tags: java, spring-boot, sha, jar-signing

I'm trying to run a spring boot application, but encounter below error:

```
2017-01-04 18:01:50 [Tomcat-startStop-1] ERROR o.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase - A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA1 signature file digest for org/bouncycastle/tsp/TimeStampTokenInfo.class
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(SignatureFileVerifier.java:499)
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:295)
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:238)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:273)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.getEntryInputStream(JarFileUrlJar.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1987)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1958)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1912)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1157)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5150)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
... 6 common frames omitted
```

Any ideas how to get over this? Or do I need to provide any other information.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm currently running into the same problem